# Proving this set claim?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$A-(A-B)=A\cap B $

How can I prove that this is a valid claim?

Comment: by proving that $x\in A-(A-B)\iff\cdots\iff x\in A\cap B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove a claim about equality of sets, prove both inclusions:

First you prove $A - (A - B) \subseteq A \cap B$. Take any $a \in A - (A - B)$. Then $a \in A$ and $a \notin A - B$. Combined, these two statements tell us that $a \in B$. And since $a \in A$ and $a \in B$, we also have that $a \in A \cap B$. Since this holds for any $a$, we have that $A - (A - B) \subseteq A \cap B$.

Try to prove the inclusion  $A - (A - B) \supseteq A \cap B$ yourself.

Comment: Not sure I understand why the first two statements imply that "a" is an element of "B"

Comment: $A - B$ is the set of elements $x \in A \wedge x \notin B$. If an element $a \notin A - B$, then either $a \notin A$ or $a \in A \wedge a \in B$. But you already know that $a \in A$.